# New field not visible in Data Designer

Tags: marketing-cloud, data-designer

We added a field to a Salesforce object and then mapped that field in the corresponding Synchronized Data Extension of Marketing Cloud, but we still can't see that field in the Data Designer. Because of this we also cannot use that field in a Decision Split in Journey Builder.
Is it only a problem of time, so that we need to wait 24 hours, or is there something else?

Comment: Depending on how much data it needs to synch after you've added the new field, it might take a few minutes, but definitely as much as 24 hours. Make sure to completely refresh Contact Builder / Journet Builder when you're checking for changes (or even log out and back in) as the interface doesn't always show them.

Comment: Actually as of now it has been more than 24 hours, but I still cannot see the field.

Answer (score 0):

[I need to have more than 50 points to add a comment, so understand this as a comment]

I was passing through the same problem, in my case, was the field visibility that was not set to Admin users in Sales Cloud (the same profile used to do the integration), since we gave this permission the problem was solved.